# How to interpret the numbers in the left column?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, layers, symbology

I ran r.report on a raster file and got this result. I cannot interpret the numbers in the left column. I'm still a beginner and I don't quite understand why the left column doesn't say land cover types (forest, grassland, cropland etc.). How to convert these numbers to vegetation types? Can someone explain? Unfortunately, I have found little guidance on this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems you are dealing with a categorical raster. In GRASS GIS you can get and set the labels of categories using the `r.category` module. You can not "convert numbers to vegetation types". You need to assign a label to each category value.

If you enter `r.category <map name>` you'll get a list of the category id's and the labels, if there are any. If you want to add labels, you use the `values=...` parameter, with a comma separated list of the category names. It must, of course, match the numeric category values. Can you post the output of `r.category` for your raster? (Please copy paste the text, NOT a screen shot).

Here's what you get, using the standard "nc_spm_08_grass" location, refering to the categorical "geology_30m" raster map:

```
micha@RMS:Documents$ r.category geology_30m
217     CZfg
262     CZlg
270     CZig
405     CZbg
583     CZve
720     CZam
766     CZg
862     CZam
910     CZbg
921     Km
945     CZbg
946     CZam
948     CZam
```

And using the `r.report` module you get the more informative:

```
micha@RMS:Documents$ r.report geology_30m         
 100%
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         RASTER MAP CATEGORY REPORT                          |
|LOCATION: nc_spm_08_grass7                           Wed Jan 25 13:49:22 2023|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          north: 228500    east: 645000                                      |
|REGION    south: 215000    west: 630000                                      |
|          res:       30    res:      30                                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|MASK: none                                                                   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|MAP: South-West Wake county: geology derived from vector map (geology_30m in |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                     Category Information                      |  cell|   %  |
|  #|description                                                | count| cover|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|217|CZfg . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 80618| 35.83|
|262|CZlg . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 22076|  9.81|
|270|CZig . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 76597| 34.04|
|405|CZbg . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . | 28190| 12.53|
|583|CZve . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  2401|  1.07|
|720|CZam . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |   536|  0.24|
|766|CZg. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |   786|  0.35|
|862|CZam . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  6858|  3.05|
|910|CZbg . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  4996|  2.22|
|921|Km . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |  1392|  0.62|
|945|CZbg . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |     1|  0.00|
|946|CZam . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |   452|  0.20|
|948|CZam . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |    97|  0.04|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|TOTAL                                                          |225000|100.00|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

HTH